# Can't find a source file at dl-trampoline.h in Eclipse Fortran Debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging, fortran

I am currently struggling with the Fortran Debugger, every time when I start with the debug module, after pressing the button "step in" or "step over", the debugger always reports some errors like following:

```
Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/elf/../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.h"

Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

Comment: Is this photran or just eclipse by itself?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Which operating system do you have? How did you install Eclipse and other relevant software?

Comment: Which Fortran compiler do you use? How did you install it? Do the programs run? Are you able to try `gdb`?